# Using fwrite to a serial port in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pic

I'm going over a MATLAB code where it's supposed to send an 8-bit binary number to a PIC via RS-232 connection. Here's the part of it where I don't understand:

```
fwrite(s,[128,130,128]);
```

I know what 's' is, `s=serial('COM1', 'BaudRate', 9600)`...
My problem is with the numbers in square brackets... what do they do? and what are they for?

p.s. - I am aware of the usual syntax to send 8-bit numbers, e.g 11111111 would be `fwrite(s, 255);` and also about precision, mode etc. but this syntax - I have no clue what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the code is sending an array/vector three 8-bit binary numbers:

```
>> dec2bin([128,130,128])

ans =

10000000
10000010
10000000
```

If you want to specify the precision, use the `fwrite(obj,A,'precision')` syntax. If you want to control both precision and mode, use the `fwrite(obj,A,'precision','mode')` syntax. For more details, refer to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/serial.fwrite.html).